# Using the attach api in Java

Tags: java

I want to use the attach API in Java 14. To my knowledge, that was moved to jdk.attach in Java 9. I ran `java --list-modules` and I had the module installed.

How do I actually use the module in my project? I tried `import jdk.attach` but that threw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use JDK14 with module definitions, this is all I needed to change to use with my module-info.java:

```
requires transitive jdk.attach;
```

Here is a simple call to run it:

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;

public class AttachApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("BEGIN");
        var vms = VirtualMachine.list();
        for (var vm : vms) {
            System.out.println("vm="+vm);
        }

        System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

The above code runs as-is with a non-module project in newer JDK if saved to a file and compiled then run, or compiled+run in one step with `java`:

```
 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java AttachApi.java
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to import it by creating a module

Comment: This example should run under JDK11+ (tried 11/14/17/20/21)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `com.sun.tools.attach.<className>` or `com.sun.tools.attach.spi.<className>`.
There are not that many resources, but this one from oracle seems like a good one: https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/the-attach-api

Comment: That api is included in tools.jar, and it was removed in Java 9.

Comment: What about this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.attach/module-summary.html

Comment: my question is how to use that in my project