# How do I use the jdk.attach module?

Tags: java, maven

Note: This is related to an earlier question. See [How do I use com.sun.tools with Java 11 without modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023967/how-do-i-use-com-sun-tools-with-java-11-without-modules) for details.

I was attempting to use the com.sun.tools package to use the `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine` class (and any others needed - I am trying to instrument my application to analyze memory usage). I cannot get it to build. I am using Oracle Java JDK 11 (11.0.17). The application also utilizes Spring Boot.

Based on what I've read so far, com.sun.tools used to be part of the JDK distribution prior to Java 9. I checked in the distribution and there is no tools.jar in $JAVA_HOME/lib. If it is no longer part of the JDK, from where do I get it? I tried adding it as a dependency in my pom.xml, but that doesn't work.

After some more digging apparently this functionality is now part of the jdk.attach "module" (whatever that is - this is a new term to me). Is there a way to access/use this feature *without* modules?

In any case, I looked into this a little more (BTW not a lot of helpful info on **HOW** to use it) and did some experimentation. Created a `module-info.java` file in the default package (which is where it seems to want it) and quickly discovered that I now have to "require" a bunch of other stuff that was previously being taken care of by my pom.xml file. This seems a bit backwards.

**What I tried - FAIL**

Even so, I tried requiring jdk.attach, but it doesn't find it. I can't import the classes I need. So much for that, eh? I ran `java --list-modules` and it shows up in the list. Wonderful, but it doesn't seem to "see" it.

I am also coming to the realization that I need to "modularize" other projects I have written so that they will all (theoretically) play together. This is turning into a pain. Why?

module-info.java:

```
module app {
  requires org.slf4j;
  requires spring.context;
  requires spring.beans;
  requires spring.boot;
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
  requires java.instrument;
  requires javassist;
  requires jdk.attach;
}
```

Output from running `java --list-modules`:

```
$ java --list-modules
java.base@11.0.17
java.compiler@11.0.17
java.datatransfer@11.0.17
java.desktop@11.0.17
java.instrument@11.0.17
java.logging@11.0.17
java.management@11.0.17
java.management.rmi@11.0.17
java.naming@11.0.17
java.net.http@11.0.17
java.prefs@11.0.17
java.rmi@11.0.17
java.scripting@11.0.17
java.se@11.0.17
java.security.jgss@11.0.17
java.security.sasl@11.0.17
java.smartcardio@11.0.17
java.sql@11.0.17
java.sql.rowset@11.0.17
java.transaction.xa@11.0.17
java.xml@11.0.17
java.xml.crypto@11.0.17
jdk.accessibility@11.0.17
jdk.attach@11.0.17
jdk.charsets@11.0.17
jdk.compiler@11.0.17
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@11.0.17
jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.17
jdk.crypto.mscapi@11.0.17
jdk.dynalink@11.0.17
jdk.editpad@11.0.17
jdk.hotspot.agent@11.0.17
jdk.httpserver@11.0.17
jdk.internal.ed@11.0.17
jdk.internal.jvmstat@11.0.17
jdk.internal.le@11.0.17
jdk.internal.opt@11.0.17
jdk.internal.vm.ci@11.0.17
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@11.0.17
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@11.0.17
jdk.jartool@11.0.17
jdk.javadoc@11.0.17
jdk.jcmd@11.0.17
jdk.jconsole@11.0.17
jdk.jdeps@11.0.17
jdk.jdi@11.0.17
jdk.jdwp.agent@11.0.17
jdk.jfr@11.0.17
jdk.jlink@11.0.17
jdk.jshell@11.0.17
jdk.jsobject@11.0.17
jdk.jstatd@11.0.17
jdk.localedata@11.0.17
jdk.management@11.0.17
jdk.management.agent@11.0.17
jdk.management.jfr@11.0.17
jdk.naming.dns@11.0.17
jdk.naming.ldap@11.0.17
jdk.naming.rmi@11.0.17
jdk.net@11.0.17
jdk.pack@11.0.17
jdk.rmic@11.0.17
jdk.scripting.nashorn@11.0.17
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@11.0.17
jdk.sctp@11.0.17
jdk.security.auth@11.0.17
jdk.security.jgss@11.0.17
jdk.unsupported@11.0.17
jdk.unsupported.desktop@11.0.17
jdk.xml.dom@11.0.17
jdk.zipfs@11.0.17
```

Comment: You should probably link your previous question for some more context: [_How do I use com.sun.tools with Java 11 without modules?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023967/how-do-i-use-com-sun-tools-with-java-11-without-modules)

Comment: It was closed (without my consent I might add).

Comment: You should clarify what is exactly the question. I understand the frustration but it is not clear exactly what you are asking. And provide some code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the attach api in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971569/using-the-attach-api-in-java)

Comment: "_without my consent I might add_" – Note that's how this site works. People with 1000+ score in a specific tag can close a question (that has that tag) as a duplicate singlehandedly. Otherwise, closing (for any reason) requires 3 votes from people with 3000+ reputation.

Comment: If you're new to modules, I recommend reading [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) for a quick overview. With the introduction of modules in Java 9, the `tools.jar` file was removed, and that code was moved into various `jdk.*` modules. Such modules should be part of the run-time image of most (all?) OpenJDK-based distributions, including Oracle JDKs. Using the `jdk.attach` module should "just work". You don't even need to modularize your code; all you have to do is import the types from that module like normal.

Comment: I read that article and a few others.

Comment: Is it only Eclipse that is having a problem? If you write the code manually, and then execute it, does it compile and run?

Comment: How do I do that? I tried letting eclipse do autocomplete, but it can't find a match for the `VirtualMachine` class. I then manually entered a new import line and tried `jdk.attach`. It doesn't see that either. What am I missing?

Comment: `jdk.attach` is the module name. Import statements work like they did in Java 8; you should have `import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine`.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried running the `mvn` commands directly on the command line and have problems there as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255147/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-slaw).

Comment: @JosephGagnon The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971569/using-the-attach-api-in-java/62979134#62979134) I showed in your [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023967/how-do-i-use-com-sun-tools-with-java-11-without-modules) works regardless of whether you use modules or not. Save the code to a file and run it. If you use modules you need module-info.java with "requires transitive jdk.attach;". If you don't use modules it will work too.

Comment: have you tried `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine` ?  That is what Eclipse suggests when using auto-complete on `VirtMach` for example (non-module project), and confirmed by [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.attach/module-summary.html)

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [*Using the attach api in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62971569/642706)